# No images on IE only black box with white x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, flexslider

I have multiple flex sliders loading on this page:
http://pamelahnelson.com/category/public-art/
Normally if you click the white 'x', they show, but I have it triggering an event to slide open the detail view.
Regardless, I think it is a security setting in the browser or similar that is blocking them, but what I really want to know is why this is being triggered?  And of course, if there is a work around so that IE doesn't do this.
I've used multiple flex sliders before without this problem.

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem. The site works for me in FF25 & IE10

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: I have no idea what white 'x' you are talking about - but the site appears to work in IE11.

Comment: I'm using IE10.  I've had 3 other people complain about it (and it does it on my computer as well). Here's a screenshot: http://pamelahnelson.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/xCapture.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that IE is aborting the image load:
[image]

This could be because the script is trying modify an element before it's fully loaded.

There is quite a bit of `js` going on in your site so look into whatever script is writing the image files to the DOM.

There is also a couple of errors in the console:

`event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:4`

`cannot call methods on isotope prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'reLayout'`

I would start with fixing the console errors since those cause IE quite a bit of heartburn.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, I had meant to clear out that relayout error.  Unfortunately that didn't fix it, BUT the aborted images for IE was the clue that sent me here: [imagesLoaded: IE9 occasionally aborts image load](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/40)   That thread didn't provide me with a clear solution but did point out that imagesLoaded was part of the problem.  I removed imagesLoaded and it cleared up the aborted images!

Answer (score 1):

In 2018 this could be related to the X-Content-type: nosniff header being emitted by the web server. This tells the browser to pay attention to the mime type (content-type header) in the image data response from the server. If it is not image/* then IE11 will decide it is dodgy and show the black-box with white-cross.  Use Fiddler or similar to observe the headers from the server to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit older post but I just had this issue and it was fixed by re-saving my images to ensure the encoding was RGB, not CMYK. IE8-IE10 don't display CMYK images.